# Volume form of a hyperbolic knot

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, knot-theory

Given a hyperbolic knot $K: S^1 \to S^3 := \mathbb{R}^3 \cup \{\infty\}$, there is a unique metric $g$ on the complement of the image with constant negative curvature, by Mostow rigidity theorem.

Assume that $K$ doesn't touch $\infty$. Can the volume form $dV_g$ be described from the three functions

$$K_i(\theta)\qquad\qquad\qquad \theta \in [0,2\pi),\quad i = 1, 2, \text{or 
 } 3?$$

Comment: Not knowing what you mean by "explicitly", would you be happy with [snappea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SnapPea) output?

Comment: I was asking for a description of $dV_g$. Any kind of description is fine.. but I hope it can be as explicit as possible. (I've taken away that word in the post.) What is snappea's output? Does it tell us what the volume form is (not the volume)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mostow Rigidity Theorem is not quite stated quite correctly in your post: $g$ is not unique **on the nose** as you have stated it. Instead, the correct statement is that if $g,g'$ are two complete, finite volume Riemannian metrics on $S^3 - K(S^1)$ of constant sectional curvature $-1$ then there exists a diffeomorphism $h : S^3 - K(S^1) \to S^3 - K(S^1)$ homotopic to the identity such that $g = h^*(g')$ (Gabai strenghthened this conclusion to "isotopic to the identity").

Because of this, it is not quite reasonable to ask for *the* volume form. One could instead ask for *a* volume form, in fact one could ask for more, one could ask for *a* Riemannian metric $g$ satisfying the desired conditions (and then with $g$ in your hands you could compute the volume form $dV_g$ at your leisure). But the point to realize here regarding uniqueness is that one can always perturb that metric $g$, by choosing a small diffeomorphism isotopic to the identity, and pushing $g$ forward to get another such metric $g'$.

So, having said all of that, the best answer I can think of in full generality is to use [SnapPea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SnapPea) to compute a decomposition of $S^3 - K(S^1)$ into ideal tetrahedra, together with a corresponding gluing diagram of ideal $\mathbb H^3$ tetrahedra. One could then write down $g$ for oneself, by using the SnapPea output to map the ideal $\mathbb H^3$ tetrahedra in that gluing diagram to the ideal tetrahedra of the given triangulation, then pushing forward the hyperbolic metrics from the ideal $\mathbb H^3$ tetrahedra.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I didn't know of "minimal ideal triangulation", and a quick search suggested that it's not too well-known. Could you recommend some reference for me to learn about it? Essentially, at the end I want to know the details of how to get the volume (in any concrete way) from the combinatorial data of the link diagram.

Comment: Volume is one of the numerical outputs of Snappea, given to you in decimal form, accurate to many decimal places.

Comment: As for references, I suggest reading about Snappea, how it works, the form of its input and its output, etc. The preliminary reading for all of this is [Thurston's lecture notes entitled "The geometry and topology of 3-manifolds"](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/).